# Curated content vs feed content deduplication

Tags: sitecore, deduplication

On the homepage of the public website we have multiple modules divided between curated content (users manually select articles/publications) vs feed content (automatically populated module based on parameters and usually sorted by date). These modules are laid out in the main body of the homepage just below the main image and the menu. These can be in mixed order and not necessarily in any particular order.

All of this content is stored in Sitecore and both module types are separated by different template types.

Sometimes certain articles show up in both module types on the homepage. We'd like to avoid this de-duplication. We have certain ways in mind of doing this but looking to see if anyone has done this before and decide on the best approach. Below are the two solutions we came up with -

1. Load all the modules which were manually curated. Store the comma separated module IDs into a hidden field. As the feed modules are loaded, ignore any articles with ID in the hidden field.
2. Load all manually curated content. Store the IDs into a list or an array in web server memory. As the feed modules are loaded, ignore any articles with ID in the list or array in memory.

The only potential problem we see here is that the order of feeds and curated modules would be jumbled up so we won't have a way of getting all curated content IDs before any of the feed content modules are loaded.

Any suggestions/ideas are welcome.

Thanks

Comment: So all the articles/publications come from the same feed? And then users manually select some of these as "featured/curated"? How do they select them? Treelist or multilist I assume?

Comment: The articles for Feed and Picked modules have the same source. The Picked Modules have hand selected articles. The feeds have automatically populated content.

The Picked content comes from a multilist field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution (assuming that you're using **web forms** and **sublayouts**) would be to extend your second solution in a way that the module with manually selected articles loads them in `OnLoad` method while the module with articles from the feed loads them in the `OnPreRender` method. This is quick and dirty solution but works if you need a quick win.

The better solution would be to create a provider class that would be a middleman between all the modules which request data and have a single instance of this class per http request (you can store it e.g. in `HttpContext.Current.Items`). All the modules would ask this provider for the articles with some priority in their `OnLoad` methods (in your case the priority of manually selected items would be higher than the feed module) and with the delegate to the method which should be executed when the articles are returned from the provider.

Then on the `PreRender` method of the page you need to inform the provider that all the requests for the articles are already registered and the provider would return the articles to all the registered modules according to their priority (with an easy way of checking the uniqueness of the content), by calling the delegate which was passed within the content request from the module. Those callbacks should bind to the repeaters or be consumed in any way you need them in the modules.

You can easily register more of the modules in the page later without any changes in the code and assure that all the links across the page are unique.

Comment: Both these modules are two different sublayouts and manually attached to the page item. Not sure if I can load one before the other because it would break from the convention of the rest of the site.